# Web api behaves "stateful" in some successive calls from different client issue

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api consumed by mobile apps. I can reproduce case with postman also with appropriate params.

Here are my postman call captured by fiddler:

```
GET http://localhost/WebApi/api/User/GetAnnouncement?id=22 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
ApiKey: someKey
AuthenticationToken: someGuid1
UserId: 6524
DeviceId: someGuid2
LocalDate: 538294155.662561
OsTypeId: 1
LoginToken: someGuid3
CompanyId: 2
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b863afdd-b04c-4a4d-b473-69d5ecef622e
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.4.0
Accept: */*
Host: localhost
cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=nk4g3zzfyi0n3xomfw5dxxxx
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

and my issue occurs in authorize action filter:

```
    public class BasicAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute
    {

    }

    public class BasicAuthorizeFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
         //!!!HERE when I debug, in watch I can see already authHeader has value "in some calls"

System.Threading.Thread.SetData( System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("authHeader"), "someValueComingFromRequestHeader" );
        }
    }
```

At the very beginning of the OnAuthorization (see !!!HERE line in the code), I can see in watch this expression:

```
System.Threading.Thread.GetData(System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("authHeader"))
```

has the value even though I expect it is always null. It has even the value from previous client.

Actually issue come to as a bug "session" mingled (I mean mixed).

This pieces code is on the my company's framework so something is weirdly wrong.
I can give as much as I can so far. Please ask any info necessary.

What could be the cause?

I am daring to ask this because it is possible the issue obvious may be.

Note: I have the same case while none debugging with two phones connected to my pc via proxy settings.

Comment: `I expect it is always null` why? this thread previously processed another request and might set value

Comment: Ilya, it is null "most of time", even calling from the same client.

Comment: and what? you don't know which thread on server will pick request

Comment: As Ilya implies, `SetData()` is a poor choice here. That data persists when the thread is returned to the thread pool, where it will be reused for another request, or an async continuation. It also won't flow across async junctions. If the code uses async and relies on that data I'd expect it is pretty flaky. The usual way identity is done in .NET is to set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. If that's too much change you could switch to using `CallContext.LogicalSetData()` (if you're using .NET4.5 or later), which in theory does not suffer from the above 2 problems.