# Thread.GetNamedDataSlot: Confict between user sessions

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

[Related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53527224/492258) (I could update that question but then content will be totally different)

[Here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx) under `GetData and SetData`, it is  indecated:

> The third approach is to use two methods in the Thread class: GetData
>   and SetData. These store data in thread-specific “slots”.
>   Thread.GetData reads from a thread’s isolated data store;
>   Thread.SetData writes to it. Both methods require a LocalDataStoreSlot
>   object to identify the slot. The same slot can be used across all
>   threads and they’ll still get separate values

and

> In this instance, we called Thread.GetNamedDataSlot, which creates a
>   named slot — this allows sharing of that slot across the application.

**Question 1** Please let me understand if it is valid: "Data is hold by data slot is hold for cross threads for .net mvc web api calls."

According to my experiment in simple web api application:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{   
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        var res1 = System.Threading.Thread.GetData(System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("authHeader"));

        if (res1  == null)
           System.Threading.Thread.SetData(System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("authHeader"), new Random().var 

        res2 = Thread.GetData(System.Threading.Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("authHeader"));

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", res2?.ToString() };
    }
}
```

1- If I set break point

`if (res1  == null)` for first call it generates random number and  for successive calls `res1  == null` is always false which means  `res1` has value and only one time random number is generated.

2- If I don't set break points

In run mode it gives randomly one of below outputs which repeats randomly, I mean i.e. 64853109 appears more than once

```
<ArrayOfstring>
    <string>value1</string>
    <string>value2</string>
    <string>64853109</string>
</ArrayOfstring>

<ArrayOfstring>
    <string>value1</string>
    <string>value2</string>
    <string>1174687568</string>
</ArrayOfstring>

<ArrayOfstring>
    <string>value1</string>
    <string>value2</string>
    <string>1367595402</string>
</ArrayOfstring>

<ArrayOfstring>
    <string>value1</string>
    <string>value2</string>
    <string>1303501153</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

**Question 2** I could opine that in when I set break point it uses always the same thread even though I try from different browser. But could you help me diagnose the issues

Note: Set and Get slot is source of the bug of current code, I am trying to identify exact issue. My intention is not to use  thread slots for future

Comment: Don't use thread slots in an asp.net context. just don't. And `new Random()` is seeded by the current time, which doesn't change that often at computer speeds.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it may sound simple question but what can I use instead, considering there is no cookie and session.